# Why C# 4.0 tolerates trailing comma in anonymous objects initialization code?

Tags: c#, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline property initialisation and trailing comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245152/inline-property-initialisation-and-trailing-comma)

Working on one of my projects (C# 4.0, Visual Studio 2010), I've accidentally discovered that code like

```
var obj = new { field1 = "Test", field2 = 3, }
```

is compiled and executed OK without any errors or even warnings and works exactly like

```
var obj = new { field1 = "Test", field2 = 3 }
```

Why does compiler tolerate the trailing coma in first example? Is this a bug in compiler or such behavior does have some purpose?

Thanks

Comment: question already answered .. twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675173/why-can-you-have-a-comma-at-the-end-of-a-collection-initializer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147333/net-enumeration-allows-comma-in-the-last-field

Comment: @nowaq My bad, should have searched SO for "trailing coma", not for "anonymous object trailing coma".

Comment: Did you notice that it seems to allow trainling semicolons also?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To determine whether or not it's a bug in the compiler, you need to look at the C# spec - in this case section 7.6.10.6, which clearly allows it:

> ```
> anonymous-object-creation-expression:    
>     new   anonymous-object-initializer
>
> anonymous-object-initializer:  
>     { member-declarator-listopt }  
>     { member-declarator-list , }
> ```

So no, it's not a compiler bug. The language was deliberately designed to allow it.

Now as for *why* the language has been designed that way - I believe it's to make it easier to add and remove values when coding. For example:

```
var obj = new { 
    field1 = "test", 
    field2 = 3,
};
```

can become

```
var obj = new { 
    field2 = 3,
};
```

or

```
var obj = new { 
    field1 = "test", 
    field2 = 3,
    field3 = 4,
};
```

*solely* by adding or removing a line. This makes it simpler to maintain code, and also easier to write code generators.

Note that this is consistent with array initializers, collection initializers and enums:

```
// These are all valid
string[] array = { "hello", };
List<string> list = new List<string> { "hello", };
enum Foo { Bar, }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing on the spec; think I might find some other interesting things there if read carefully :)

Comment: I think the strongest point here is for code generators. And let's all face it, it's a really nice feature that we wish all languages had.

Comment: That's what framework like drupal, etc. does and people label that as bad practice. ???

Comment: @codingbiz: Who labels *exactly what* as bad practice?

Comment: @JonSkeet In drupal, PHP arrays are declared with trailing commas and I have seen it been condemned on this forum. Perhaps by those who don't love drupal. As long as it makes coding easier, I think it's OK. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @codingbiz: It's entirely possible that the same people would dislike it being used in C#. You shouldn't assume it's *just* a platform bias.

Comment: This comes as a real shock to me; I always assumed it was invalid, so I never did it. Thanks for setting it out so clearly.

Comment: Is it consistent with non-anonymous object initializers, like `new ClassName { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 2, }`?

Comment: @Triynko: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 18):

One reason the trailing commas is good is because of Source Compares. If you update the source and use a source compare tool, then the source compare tool will only show 1 line changed (the new field3. If there was no trailing comma, then source compare will show 2 lines changed because you had to add the comma after the number 3.

```
var obj = new {
  field1 = "Test",
  field2 = 3,
  }

var obj = new {
  field1 = "Test",
  field2 = 3,
  field3 = "New",
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

To make deleting the last field easier, I suppose. There is really no ambiguity introduced in the syntax by doing this, so it just makes life a bit easier.