# ASP.NET C# System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerable Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

Getting this weird LINQ error.

title =
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String

Here is the code I have:

```
if (Request.QueryString["Keywords"] != null){
        string keywords = Request.QueryString["Keywords"];
            string myAppID = "HIDDEN";
            var xml = XDocument.Load("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=" + myAppID + "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=" + keywords + "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=5");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";
            var titles = from item in xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "title")
                              select new{
                                  title = xml.Descendants(ns + "title").Select (x => x.Value),
                              };
        foreach (var item in titles){
                Label1.Text += item;
            } 
        }
```

Here what the XML looks like:

```
<findItemsByKeywordsResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<searchReslut count="5">
<item>
    <title></title>
</item>
<item>
    <title></title>
</item>
<item>
    <title></title>
</item>
```

Trying to get it to output correctly.

Comment: I see an extra comma at the end of line 8.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message to me.  Do you have the actual error message?

Comment: @RobertHarvey and why would the comma be OK?

Comment: debug doesn't show me any errors persay. and comma makes no difference.

Comment: @Codesleuth: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253413

Comment: @allencoded: Then you're going to need to be more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: Just try change that line to `title = item.Value` - it seems obvious to me it's `ToString()` the collection you're selecting. EDIT: should post as answer, hold on.

Comment: Set a break point in debug and hover over "item" in your foreach loop. See if it's an object or a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
title = xml.Descendants(ns + "title").Select (x => x.Value)
```

change to

```
title = item.Value
```

EDIT as ChrisGessler suggests, but with my suggestion:

```
if (Request.QueryString["Keywords"] != null)
{
    string keywords = Request.QueryString["Keywords"];
    string myAppID = "HIDDEN";
    var xml = XDocument.Load(/* snip */);
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";
    var titles = xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "title").Select(x => x.Value);
    Label1.Text = String.Join(null, titles);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't the select new part be removed as well?  select item.Value

Comment: Well if we were to look at the question as a challenge for optimization, then sure we could pull it apart and get much cleaner code. My answer was only to solve OP's problem, but feel free to post an answer with a rework :)

Comment: question? How can I output it a array?

Comment: In the example I wrote, you can see that `xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "title").Select(x => x.Value)` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, which you can simply do `.ToArray()` to get an array. So: `titles.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this:

```
var titles = from item in xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "title")                               
             select new{                                   
                title = xml.Descendants(ns + "title").Select (x => x.Value)};
```

Should be:

```
var titles = from item in xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "title")                               
             select item.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

quick snippet

.. as example when using mvc grid in a cshtml razor page..

..

```
 .RenderValueAs(
       item => @Html.ActionLink(
        (
         from tsrItem in (item.<yourColumnName>) 
         where tsrItem.<IdField> == item.<IdField> 
         select tsrItem.<desiredColumn>
        ).FirstOrDefault(),
```

..     hope it helps